# Можно ли получить значение параметра вызываемой функции?

Tags: c#

Допустим, есть у меня код

```
int a = 0;
Calculate(a);
```

И функция

```
void Calculate(int a){ for(int i=0; i<100; i++) a++; }
```

Существуют ли способы получить значение a из экземпляра вызываемой функции?

Comment: `int Calculate` `return a;`

Comment: Параметр существует только во время работы функции, если хотите узнать чему он стал равен, возвращайте его через return или сделайте параметр `ref int a`, тогда изменения в функции затронут переменную, которую вы передаете, и она тоже изменится.

Comment: @trollingchar, спасибо, я забыл, что так вообще можно. То, что я и хотел